# Prompt File Download to Phone from NFC Tag

Tags: nfc, ndef, open-nfc

Rather than an NFC tag prompting a phone to visit a URL in the phone's browser, I would like the NFC tag to prompt the phone to simply download an .mp3 file hosted on a server (similarly to hitting "save target as" from a browser instead of clicking on a link that would bring you to a page).

The goal in general: to have a phone scan an NFC tag and receive or hear (or have access to) an audio file, but to not have the URL of the audio file's host location to be outwardly visible, such that the link to the file location would not easily be visible or shared.

Any and all solutions would be welcome!

Comment: To access a resource on the Internet, that resource must be known to the device at *some* point in *some* way.  It could be the case that said resource shifts between different servers periodically but even then I don't see much point in this, since either you or the device initiating the connection needs to understand where it came from.

Comment: Hi @Makoto - thank you for your response. Yes, the device would certainly know where it were coming from, but I meant that the tag would not prompt a browser to open such that the web address would be actually visible to the eye. Is this possible?

Comment: Unless the end user had a different application on their phone to handle HTTP requests with, probably not.